# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Licence Key can't be applied

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, licensing, enterprise, msdn

I have a crazy Licence issue with my VS2015 Enterprise. I'm a student and my school provide us many MS products. In the past and for the other version of VS, I download the iso in my account, and they generate a licence key and i just need applied it after the installation. With VS2015 Enterprise, i have do the same, I have a legit key on my OntheHub MS account when I have take the iso. 
The Expire date finish in 2017 and my school tell me that my account is valid (for the other product of MS it works well).

But something is wrong in VS 2015. I can't apply the key. So at first, i have use the trial licence, but now, it will expire in 3 days.
I go to the licence key windows but when I touch "apply", nothing happen.

I have try :

- format my computer
- download a new ISO
- repair VS
- Uninstall and install again VS, with a clean in registry too.

I also look a lot of solution in Stackoverflow and MS Community. 
Nothing work... 
I'm running on Windows 10 with VS 2015 Enterprise Update 3.

Any Help ?